# xen server windows template sysprep Autounattend

Tags: windows, xen, sysprep, template

Got a Xen Server Template Windows 2008 R2, thats had alot of things already set (disk size, server manager disabled etc, etc)

We spin up, windows patch host and re-run sysprep

My question is, can you re-run sysrep with autounattend.xml ?? to disable some other settings

also run a powershell script post-sysprep

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While ideally Sysprep (and Generalize) would only be run once on an image before it hits production, it is not unheard of to run it more than once. There are some limitations of re-preparing an image, such as the rearm limit. [See the Sysprep, SkipRearm, and Image Build Best Practices post on the Ask the Core Team Blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2011/05/11/sysprep-skiprearm-and-image-build-best-practices.aspx).

You can inject the answer file in a number of locations documented in [the Windows Setup Automation Overview article in the TechNet Library](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh824950).